# Bootstrap modal nonfunctional in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

(I know there's a bunch of questions like this, but none seem to answer my specific situation.)

I'm trying to get a bootstrap modal to display in a Rails view, but the associated button simply does nothing - clicking it has no effect at all beyond the button interaction effect. As far as I know bootstrap in general is set up to work properly; that doesn't seem to be my issue.

Modal html, most of which is directly copied from the bootstrap documentation:

```
<div id="new_event">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-event-modal">+</button>

  <div id="new-event-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">add an event!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Text! <!--form goes here -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `custom.scss` has `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap"`, and my `application.js` has `//= require bootstrap-sprockets`. Other javascript things are working perfectly well, and other bootstrap things are working perfectly well. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

That is not going to work. If you are using Rails 6, there is a very specific way to add Bootstrap to your rails app. I have described it on github:
https://github.com/overdrivemachines/bootstrap-rails

Comment: Editing my app to contain the things in that description that the app didn't have (in this case, just some `import` lines in `application.js` and the `application.scss` file inside `/javascript/packs`) did not cause the modal to appear.